# Proper way of typesetting dot over indexed variable

Tags: typography

What is the proper way to put a dot over an indexed variable, like for Netwon's derivative notation?  For typesetting reasons, I prefer `\dot{x}_i`, but my colleage argues that it's an operator on `x_i` and hence it must be `\dot{x_i}`, which looks hideous if the index is longer, like `\dot{x_\text{max}}`. It becomes ever worse since I want to typeset vectors in boldface using the `bm` package, but then the dot is boldface as well, and that is certainly incorrect. Who has some wisdom for me?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\bm {#1}}}
\begin{document}

Is it $\dot{x}_i$ or $\dot{x_i}$? What about $\dot{x_{max}}$? \par
And what about $\vect{\dot{x}_i}$ or $\vect{\dot{x}}_i$, 
or maybe better $\dot{\vect{x}}_\vect{i}$?

\end{document}
```

Which yields this:
[image]

Comment: Tell your colleague to "stuff it", in a nice way, of course.

Comment: Definitely `\dot{x}_{<subscript>}` and `\dot{\bm{x}}_{<subscript>}`

Comment: `\do{x}_i` tell your colleague that typesetting is not mathematics.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks.  I can answer my own question from egreg's and David Carlisle's answers:

Use `\dot{x}_{<subscript>}` and `\dot{\bm{x}}_{<subscript>}`, since typesetting is not mathematics.

Comment: This answer was already given by @egreg in the comments above.

Comment: You can only close a question with an answer. That's why I gave it.

Comment: No, you can close any question, regardless of whether it has an answer or not. Furthermore, it would be nice to name the author of the answer and not just pretend to be its own.